# JMS topic get clientID's

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

Can i get ClientID's of all jms topic subscribers? I use Jboss AS 6 (HornetQ).

Off course, i can send query to all of them and read replies, but i'm looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: `JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1090/jmxrmi"), new HashMap<String, String>());
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
            `

Comment: `TopicControl topicControl = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(
                    mbsc, ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT.getJMSTopicObjectName("/topic/notifierTopic"),
                    TopicControl.class, false
            );
            Object[] onlineUsers = topicControl.listAllSubscriptions();`

Comment: import org.hornetq.api.core.management.ObjectNameBuilder;
import org.hornetq.api.jms.management.TopicControl;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HornetQ you can list all the core-queues using JMX-management.

You can just list the queues under org.hornetq.core (on the JMX view). The client-id will just be part of the name.